# How to compare and calculate each row to all other rows in the same column and table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, haversine

My data looks like this, a place with their coordinates details

```
Place   Latitude    Longitude
A   2.314   97.6110288
B   3.425   98.6925504
C   4.1231  99.774072
D   5.096466667 100.8555936
E   6.001016667 101.9371152
F   6.905566667 103.0186368
G   7.810116667 104.1001584
H   8.714666667 105.18168
I   9.619216667 106.2632016
J   10.52376667 107.3447232
K   11.42831667 108.4262448
L   12.33286667 109.5077664
M   13.23741667 110.589288
N   14.14196667 111.6708096
O   15.04651667 112.7523312
P   15.95106667 113.8338528
```

So the table looks like this
what i want to do is compare the place to all the other place by counting the distance in between places. and if it fulfills the criteria, we add one to output

so for example

We compare the distance of Place A to , B,C,D,E,F,G

so

```
    for example A-B , distance = 100
A-C, distance = 70
A-D, distance = 50
A-E,distance = 120
A-F,distance = 140      
A-G,distance = 175
A-H, DIstance=80
A-I,Distance =40
A-J,Distance=190
A-K,distance=209
A-L,distance=109
A-M,A-N,A-O,A-P=150
```

and we go a conditional so if i want to only take the one that is larger than 151 , it will return 3 for the row

and this will calculate for all rows in the table

the output example is like this

output expected

```
Place   Latitude    Longitude   Bigger Than 151
A   2.314   97.6110288  3
B   3.425   98.6925504  5
C   4.1231  99.774072   1
D   5.096466667 100.8555936 3
E   6.001016667 101.9371152 2
F   6.905566667 103.0186368 1
G   7.810116667 104.1001584 5
H   8.714666667 105.18168   2
I   9.619216667 106.2632016 4
J   10.52376667 107.3447232 1
K   11.42831667 108.4262448 0
L   12.33286667 109.5077664 0
M   13.23741667 110.589288  0
N   14.14196667 111.6708096 0
O   15.04651667 112.7523312 0
P   15.95106667 113.8338528 0
```

i also can use python for power bi, if power query/dax power Bi may not be able to solve this .

Thank you

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller chunks. I'd start by adding a column with the distances from `A` in Power Query.  Then you can rank and filter however you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start by cross-joining your Places table with itself: [Cross join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/cross-join)
2. Next calculate the (haversine) distances between all places: [Use Power Query to Calculate Distance](http://www.girlswithpowertools.com/2014/05/distance/)
3. Finally filter the *Distance* column > 151 and GroupBy *Place*, counting the rows.

Of cause everything can be done in DAX as well, but all calculations will run "live" in the report, which will impact the performance with 100k x 100k rows.

Comment: Hi thank you , but i have 100k rows would this still be viable?

Comment: Power BI is made for **Big Data**, which starts at 10M rows.

Comment: hi i cannot seem to complete the cross join from the table with itself. i seem to be able to load it out in smaller sample,

Comment: Apologies if it seems like that, i was just trying the method and lost track of time. Cheers!